# Capturing test traffic with BrowserMobProxy

Tags: java, selenium, performance-testing, browsermob, browsermob-proxy

I am trying to setup BrowserMobProxy to capture performance data. However im not having much success at the moment. Most if not all of the documentation i can find seems to use the now deprecated ProxyServer. And the documentation on the [BrowserMobProxy git](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) does not provide any complete examples(unless im missing something).

So at the moment i have the proxy server up and running and also have created a har. But at the end of the test suite there is not much content in the file.

```
{"log":{"version":"1.2","creator":{"name":"BrowserMob Proxy","version":"2.1.0-beta-1-littleproxy","comment":""},"pages":[{"id":"pageName","startedDateTime":"2015-07-08T16:43:57.838+01:00","title":"pageName","pageTimings":{"comment":""},"comment":""}],"entries":[],"comment":""}}
```

Here is the proxy setup i currently have:

Run before each test suite in @BeforeSuite:

```
        BrowserMobProxy server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        server.start(0);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        server.newHar();
```

And then after the tests have finished in @AfterSuite

```
        String timestamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);
        String strFilePath =  timestamp+ ".har";
        Har har = server.getHar();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
        har.writeTo(fos);
        server.stop();
        driver.quit();
```

Can anybody fill me in on where i need to go from here? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out for anybody else that stumbles across this. The problem was that the site im working on uses ssl. So i needed to setSSLProxy for the selenium proxy configuration to "trustAllSSLCertificates". So now im left with this as my browsermob proxy config:

```
server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
server.start(0);
Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(server);
proxy.setSslProxy("trustAllSSLCertificates");
```